# A graph with two blocks containing exactly one cut-vertex

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Here is the following theorem (Chang, Graphs and Digraphs 4th edition):
*Let G be a graph with one or more cut-vertices. Then, among the blocks of G, there are at least two which contain exactly one cut-vertex of G.*

Do somebody has a hint?
Is there a way to prove it without using a subtree?

I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two hints:

1. A cut-vertex must separate at least two blocks. (Why?)
2. Can two blocks share more than one cut-vertex? (Review the definition of a cut-vertex if you are not sure.)